# F# Serialization of Record types

Tags: serialization, f#, xml-serialization

I know how to serialize in F# using mutable objects, but is there a way to serialize/deserialize using record types using either XmlSerializer or the DataContractSerializer? looks like there is a way to do this for a discriminated union using the KnownType attribute, but i am looking for a way to use non-mutable records without default constructor...

Comment: i ended up just using xml parsing, which was just as well in my case, what i tried did not work to produce clean xml, even with Tomas's suggestions to use System.Xml.Serialization's attributes, my suspicion  was that it was not going to work, but i decided to try anyways and they did not, i believe because the datacontract's namespace ignores these. my requirement was to use non-mutable records for this exercise, but if your goal is just xml serialization, then it's no different than using it in any other .net language, just create classes, decorate them and use XmlSerializer, it will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sample [code for reading data from Freebase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jomo_fisher/neat-sample-f-and-freebase) by Jomo Fisher uses `DataContractJsonSerializer` to load data into immutable F# records. The declaration of the record that he uses looks like this:

```
[<DataContract>]
type Result<'TResult> = { // '
    [<field: DataMember(Name="code") >]
    Code:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name="result") >]
    Result:'TResult // '
    [<field: DataMember(Name="message") >]
    Message:string }
```

The key point here is that the the `DataMember` attribute is attached to the underlying field that's actually used to store the data and not to the read-only property that the F# compiler generates (using the `field:` modifier on the attribute).

I'm not 100% sure if this is going to work with other types of serialization (probably not), but it may be a useful pointer to start with...

**EDIT** I'm not sure if I'm missing something here, but the following basic example works fine for me:

```
module Demo

#r "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"

open System.IO  
open System.Text  
open System.Xml 
open System.Runtime.Serialization
 
type Test = 
  { Result : string[]
    Title : string }
 
do
  let sb = new StringBuilder()
  let value = { Result = [| "Hello"; "World" |]; Title = "Hacking" }
  let xmlSerializer = DataContractSerializer(typeof<Test>); 
  xmlSerializer.WriteObject(new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)), value)
  let sr = sb.ToString()
  printfn "%A" sr

  let xmlSerializer = DataContractSerializer(typeof<Test>); 
  let reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(sr))
  let obj = xmlSerializer.ReadObject(reader) :?> Test
  printfn "Reading: %A" obj
```

**EDIT 2** If you want to generate cleaner XML then you can add attributes like this:

```
[<XmlRoot("test")>] 
type Test = 
  { [<XmlArrayAttribute("results")>] 
    [<XmlArrayItem(typeof<string>, ElementName = "string")>] 
    Result : string[]
    [<XmlArrayAttribute("title")>] 
    Title : string }
```

Comment: this is a start, but the xml that's being generated is not "clean", i mean the tags are like "FSI_0132.Test" instead of Test and Title_x0040_ instead of title . i also looks like cannot set the xml tags on the type with attributes like [<XmlElement "foo" >] . in other words, the xml looks intermediate, not something that i could really use. btw, Tomas, i am starting to read your Real-World Functional Programming book, it looks really good so far.

Comment: The namespace "FSI_0132" is generated by F# Interactive - in compiled code, it would be replaced with your actual namespace. Not sure about the property name, though.

Comment: @Joel: right, i understand that, but my goal is to have clean xml without any namespace information, like you would if you tried to deserialize using XmlSerializer class in .net

Comment: @Alex: I tried adding attributes to control the generated XML and it works fine too - see the second edit. (this time the attributes need to be added to the generated properties though)

Comment: Tomas, i am not 100% sure why, but my output looks like this:<Program.Test xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <Result_x0040_ xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d2p1:string>Hello</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>World</d2p1:string>
    </Result_x0040_>
    <Title_x0040_>Hacking</Title_x0040_>
</Program.Test> notice, that the attributes seem to be ignored

Answer (score 15):

Beginning with F# 3.0, serialization of record types is now supported by applying the `CliMutableAttribute` to the type.  Example:

```
[<CLIMutable>] 
type MyRecord = { Name : string; Age : int }
```

This example is taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx, which includes a discussion of this feature and three other new features in F# 3.0: triple-quoted strings, automatic properties, and unused variable warnings.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't use XmlSerializer or the DataContractSerializer, but [Json.NET 6.0 includes nice F# support.](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support)

It looks like this:

```
type TestTarget = 
    { a: string
      b: int }

[<TestFixture>]
type JsonTests() = 
    [<Test>]
    member x.``can serialize``() = 
        let objectUnderTest = { TestTarget.a = "isa"; b = 9 }
        let jsonResult: string = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectUnderTest)
        printfn "json is:\n%s" jsonResult
        let xmlResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonResult, "root")
        printfn "xml is:\n%s" (xmlResult.OuterXml)

        let jsonRoundtrip = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestTarget>(jsonResult)
        printfn "json roundtrip: %A" jsonRoundtrip

        let xmlAsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlResult, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true)
        printfn "object -> json -> xml -> json:\n%A" xmlAsJson
        let xmlRoundtrip = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestTarget>(xmlAsJson)
        printfn "xml roundtrip:\n%A" xmlRoundtrip

        Assert.That(true, Is.False)
        ()

json is:
{"a":"isa","b":9}
xml is:
<root><a>isa</a><b>9</b></root>
json roundtrip: {a = "isa";
 b = 9;}
object -> json -> xml -> json:
"{
  "a": "isa",
  "b": "9"
}"
xml roundtrip:
{a = "isa";
 b = 9;}
```

Comment: awesome for showing a way to use record types without needing the `[<CLIMutable>]` attr (just upgrade your newtonsoft)

Comment: I found that this did not respect case sensitivity of member names (they were always converted to lower case).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this series of annotations on the properties of classes to format the XML:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
[XmlElement("some-element")]
[XmlAttribute("some-attribute")]
[XmlArrayAttribute("collections")]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(SomeClass), ElementName = "item")]
```

I use the attributes on my c# classes, but deserialize in F# (c# classes are ina  referenced lib).

in f#:

```
use file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
let serializer= XmlSerializer(typeof<SomeClass>)
let docs = serializer.Deserialize file :?> SomeClass
```

Comment: that's cool, but the requirement is to use non-mutable types, so this approach will not work since the class will have mutable fields