# F# WebApi using record types doesn't give the desired XML output

Tags: f#, asp.net-web-api, f#-3.0

**The working code is at the bottom of this question!**

**With the following WebApi controller in F#:**

```
namespace FsWeb.Controllers

open System.Web
open System.Web.Mvc
open System.Net.Http
open System.Web.Http
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq;
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders;

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"conn string">

[<CLIMutable>] 
type ViewModelRec = { CustomerId : string }

type ValuesController() =
    inherit ApiController()
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    do
        db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out

    // GET /api/values
    member x.Get(take:int, skip:int) = 
        let t = take
        let s = skip

        query {
            for row in db.Reservations do
            skip s 
            take t
            select { CustomerId = row.CustomerId.ToString() }
        }
```

**The XML output is:**

```xml
<ArrayOfViewModelRec xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FsWeb.Controllers">
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>A98971F0-5F93-4F0D-B5AC-95E161458381</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>60DF7CF6-91FB-4BBE-AD6B-FE0CAA32F60E</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>84506E40-139C-4DD1-B396-3CE13DC20996</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>D9FABC12-9B19-46C2-9776-E31171A302D5</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>B1B6C617-AA0E-46A9-A0B6-312A229BE178</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>BAB194AE-CD2C-400F-B81E-2A293C50C404</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>AE001AB4-8410-43BF-9C93-AE5A2EACFDF5</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>2DDBDB91-9307-4BF7-865F-C6237D09D542</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>A3E93E5C-2B7E-4B8D-8AAD-AD245E32093F</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
<ViewModelRec>
<CustomerId_x0040_>B64B814F-9B4C-46BD-A804-648309FA7DD0</CustomerId_x0040_>
</ViewModelRec>
</ArrayOfViewModelRec>
```

When I use a class instead, the naming looks correct (without the *x0040* tag).

Anyone a suggestion?

**Updated: Solution:**

```
namespace FsWeb.Controllers

open System.Web
open System.Web.Mvc
open System.Net.Http
open System.Web.Http
open System.Runtime.Serialization;
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq;
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders;

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"here comes the connection string">

[<DataContract>]
type ViewModelRec = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name="CustomerId")>]
    CustomerId : string }

type ValuesController() =
    inherit ApiController()
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    do
        db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out

    member x.Get(take:int, skip:int) = 
        let t = take
        let s = skip

        query {
            for row in db.Reservations do
            skip s 
            take t
            select { CustomerId = row.CustomerId.ToString() }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not an F# expert but as far as I know, record types property getters are backed by internal fields of the same name, only with "@" at the end. In your case "CustomerId@".

The serializer then chooses to serialize these backing fields, instead of the public getters, same as when you'd have a C# class with [Serializable] attribute on it.

It should work when you use DataContract/DataMember - see [F# Serialization of Record types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034932/f-serialization-of-record-types)

Comment: This surely fixes my issue! I will mark your comment as the answer. This also explains why using classes works fine because then I am defining the property get;set; that are used.